# Is it possible to avoid breaking on a debugger statement in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to reverse engineer a heavily obfuscated JS and one of the tricks the author does is to continuously call the `debugger` statement from within an anonymous function:

[image: demo]

Unfortunately, I cannot right click and **Never pause** it, because each time the function is called a new anonymous function is spawned. The only way for me to inspect the code with DevTools open is to toggle the **Disable all breakpoints** button, but that disables my breakpoints too.

Is there any way to *disable exclusively all `debugger` statements* in Chrome?

In case there isnt, *what could be done to bypass this anti-tampering trick?*

Comment: You can also try overriding/spoofing something that runs that code by inspecting Call stack, like maybe `window.setTimeout`.

Answer (score 9):

Download the offending `webworker.js` file to your local drive, and use a text editor to replace all occurrences of "debugger" with ";".

Then use a Chrome extension to replace the *remote* resource with your *local* modified version.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii?hl=en

**FYI**: I do not endorse the above extension. It was just the first I found via Google.

Comment: The screenshot didn't do justice, webworker.js file has nothing to do with it. The script that spawns the anon function is the main website's script, and as it's completely obfuscated, I cannot find the code that actually does that to disable it, particularly without the ability to add my own breakpoints.

Comment: @emi It's still the same process. You download the main script, modify it and then replace it. Keep in mind that you can add JS source code that changes how it is de-obfuscated. Can you share the URL to this script file?

Comment: Sure, this is the [script](https://pokehuntr.com/js/pokehuntr.js) and the [main website](https://pokehuntr.com).

I've been actually replacing parts of the code directly via DevTools, using local overrides. It's been working fine, and I've managed to rev. eng. quite a bit of the code, but now I'm stuck and removing that debugger spawning would really help.

Comment: @emi that is a nasty obfuscated file. It looks like everything is executed via the `_0x5e32f1` function. If you modify this function you can call `toString()` to see if a function contains the word "debugger", and then NOT call that function. I assume they thought of this attack and it might not be that simple, but that is what I would first try.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for an old Chrome prior to 2021 where we could hack the internals of devtools itself by using devtools-on-devtools:

1. undock devtools into a separate window
2. press the full devtools hotkey - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
3. paste the following code in this new devtools window console and run it

```
{
  const rx = /\bdebugger\b/y;
  const eventSymbol = SDK.DebuggerModel.Events.DebuggerPaused;
  const original = [...SDK.targetManager._modelListeners.get(eventSymbol)]
    .find(v => v.listener.name === '_debuggerPaused');
  const debuggerModel = SDK.targetManager.models(SDK.DebuggerModel)[0];

  SDK.targetManager.removeModelListener(
    SDK.DebuggerModel,
    eventSymbol,
    original.listener,
    original.thisObject);

  SDK.targetManager.addModelListener(
    SDK.DebuggerModel,
    eventSymbol,
    async function({data}) {
      if (data._debuggerPausedDetails.reason === 'other') {
        const frame = data._debuggerPausedDetails.callFrames[0];
        const code = await frame._script.requestContent();
        let {columnNumber: x, lineNumber: y} = frame._location;
        let pos = 0;
        while (y--)
          pos = code.indexOf('\n', pos) + 1;
        rx.lastIndex = Math.max(0, pos + x);
        if (rx.test(code)) {
          debuggerModel.resume();
          return;
        }
      }
      original.listener.apply(original.thisObject, arguments);
    });
}
```

Notes:

- You can save this code as a [snippet in devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) to run it later.
- To quickly switch docking mode in the main devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- Theoretically, it's not that hard to put this code into `resources.pak` file in Chrome application directory. There are several tools to decompile/build that file so just add the code to any script that has something like SDK.DebuggerModel.Events.DebuggerPaused inside. One can even write a tool that does that automatically on Chrome update.

Comment: Woah, that's quite cool! Unfortunately it didn't worked [*quite* well](https://imgur.com/a/46j56dU), but it sure helps, thank you!

Comment: Can't say why it blinks for you. Didn't blink at all in my simple test script.

Comment: Its also blinking on my project. The page is now pausing and starting on and on.

Comment: As of 3/2022 I'm getting "SDK not defined" error. Is there a newer version of this that works?

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the in the gutter on the line with the `debugger` statement and select "Never pause here".

[image]