# Ignore debugger; statement but still evaluate my own breakpoints in dev-tools/IDE

Tags: javascript, gulp, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, javascript-debugger

### Introduction

So really annoying thing is that a colleague has a habit of committing his breakpoints as `debugger;` directly into the sourcecode.

It's annoying because you either have to disable all breakpoints, or you have to suffer through their debug statements in order to use your own.

### Question

So, what process do you guys have to work around this? I have thought of three different options (next).

### My current options

**I'm going to add my options here since they are also a valid answer. Looking forward however to other people's answers as well.**

1. Add conditional breakpoints in debug tools evaluating to false.
2. Instead of calling `debugger;` wrap this in a custom function. Put an if statement inside with a flag true/false so that you can disable them in one shot.
3. Remove `debugger` statements during source file processing in gulp.

Comment: re 1, I simply right-click and choose "never stop here". Another option or rather a hack is [autocontinuing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972086) which might be useful to combat a web page that spits anonymous evals with `debugger` inside to prevent convenient debugging ("never stop" won't work as the source is always different).

Comment: @wOxxOm I completely missed "never stop" . That's a valid answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add my options here since they are also a valid answer.
Looking forward however to other people's answers as well.

1. Add conditional breakpoints in debug tools evaluating to false.
2. Instead of calling `debugger;` wrap this in a custom function. Put an if statement inside with a flag true/false so that you can disable them in one shot.
3. Remove `debugger` statements during source file processing in gulp.